# Que vous rencontrez ou rencontriez

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

Which sentence is grammatically correct:

- Nous sommes navrés pour le problème que vous rencontrez
- Nous sommes navrés pour le problème que vous rencontr**i**ez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem exists because the speaker is sorry about it so the indicative (*que vous **rencontrez***) is correct.

The subjunctive would work in:

> Que vous **rencontriez** un problème nous navrerait.

although this form would me more natural.

> *Nous serions navrés de tout problème que vous **pourriez renconter.***

Comment: Interesting. the subjunctive is used to express doubt. In the example that you provided, the person might face some problems or not. Thank you Jilliagre

Answer (score 1):

Only the first sentences is correct; but in the end, the decision as to  whether  it is grammatical or not is a matter of context.

If there is a problem, and it has just been found then the first sentence applies and is correct as is.

- Nous sommes navrés pour le problème que vous rencontrez. (*présent de l'indicatif*)

If the person writing or talking is referring to possible problems, then something like the second sentence is proper, but he tense must be changed; it can't be the "imparfait de l'indicatif" (rencontriez) ([conjugation](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/rencontrer.html)), which is nonsense, and it must be the "conditionnel présent".

- Nous sommes navrés pour tout problème que vous rencont**reriez**. (*conditionnel présent*)

Also, you must change the determiner in this latter case because any problem that might occur cannot be known beforehand.

Comment: *(Que) vous rencontriez* can be either *imparfait de l'indicatif* or *présent du subjonctif*, I overlook the former, you overlook the latter...